# Extract unique values from horizontal row and spill down in a list vertically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique

I have many values in row 5.
I want to extract the unique values in row 5, and present them in a vertical list.

When I throw a unique-formula on row 5, the list is created horisontally sideways, not downwards.

The scenario is described in this picture:
[Picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol5gU.png)

Comment: have you looked at the TRANSPOSE function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TRANSPOSE`

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(row5,1))
```

or

```
=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(row5))
```

where *row5* is your range,